# Nginx reverse proxy with error 502 only with dynamic port by map

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, proxy

I am try to map my backend NodeJS Docker containers from ports to subdomains. To this, I try configure:

```
map $sub $prt {
        include /var/www/ports.map;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate         /var/...;
        ssl_certificate_key     /var/...;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /var/...;

        server_name ~^(?P<sub>.+?)-api\.cnpgc\.embrapa\.br$;

        location / {
                add_header x-sub "$sub";
                add_header x-prt "$prt";

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:$prt;
        }

}
```

However, when try to access, e.g., "cria-certo-api.cnpgc.embrapa.br" I get error "502 Bad Gateway". If I change the last line from

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:$prt;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
```

The proxy works fine! So, the error appears caused by presence of variable "$prt" in URL. This not make sense.

I debug my map with lines:

```
add_header x-sub "$sub";
add_header x-prt "$prt";
```

And it works too. Any help?

Comment: There is probably an error message in the error log which explains the cause of the problem in greater detail. My guess is that you need to include a `resolver` directive.

Comment: Hi @Rain Maker, did you found any solution?